# Vector independence: multiplication vs linear combination

Tags: linear-algebra

My text sometimes states that two vectors are independent because they are not multiples of each other. Isn't there always the chance that they could be a linear combination of each other?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have only *two* vectors, when you look at *one* of then there is only one other, and a linear combination of one vector is the same as a multiple of it.

More precisely, if
$$ av+bw=0 $$
is a nontrivial linear combination so $a,b$ are not bot zero, then
$$ v = \frac{-b}{a}w $$
so they are indeed multiples of each other.

Comment: Just to be finicky, one of $a, b$ could well be zero, but not both, so WLOG you are supposing $a \ne 0$, etc

Answer (score 0):

1. Let $x$ and $y$ dependent vectors. Then there are scalars $s$ and $t$ such that

$0=sx+ty$ and $(s,t) \ne (0,0)$. Without loss of generality we can assume that $s \ne 0$. Then

$$x=- \frac{t}{s}y.$$

2. If  $x$ and $y$ vectors such that $x=ry$ for some scalar $r$, then $0=x-ry$. Hence $x$ and $y$ dependent.

Answer (score 0):

$x,y$ are linearly independent iff $\forall a,b\;(ax+by=0\implies a=b=0).$

So if $x,y$ are linearly independent then $$x=cx+dy\implies x(c-1)+dy=0\implies c-1=d=0 $$ and similarly $$y=ex+fy\implies ex+(f-1)y=0\implies e=f-1=0.$$ So the only way to write $x$ as a linear combination of $x$ and $y$ is $x=1x+0y.$ We do not have $x=0x+dy=dy$ for any $d$.

Similarly, the only way to write $y$ as a linear combination of $x$ and $y$ is $y=0x+1y.$ We do not have $y=ex+0y=ex$ for any $e$.